# Find real solution $x$ in order to $x + \sqrt{2020}$ and $\dfrac{5}{x} -\sqrt{2020}$ are integers

Tags: integers

$x + \sqrt{2020}$ and $\dfrac{5}{x} - \sqrt{2020}$ are integers

$\Rightarrow x + \dfrac{5}{x}$ is an integer

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{x^2 + 5}{x}$ is an integer

$\Rightarrow x^2 + 5\ \vdots\ x$

$\Rightarrow x^2 + 5 - x^2\ \vdots\ x$

$\Rightarrow 5\ \vdots\ x$

Is it the right way?

Any idea? Or any better way to solve this problem?

Please help !!!

Comment: What does $a \vdots b$ mean?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $x$ is an integer, when you subtract $x$?

Comment: What if $x$ is not an integer?  What is divides for a noninteger?

Comment: Hint: Let $a=x+\sqrt{2020}$ be an integer. Then $b=\frac{5}{a-\sqrt{2020}}-\sqrt{2020}$ is an integer. Do again what you did to $x$, but use $a$ instead.

Comment: @StefanLafon It seems to be an idiosyncratic notation for $b\mid a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Edward H](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/632577/edward-h)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978351/find-real-solution-x-in-order-to-x-sqrt2020-and-dfrac5x-sqrt20#comment8208255_3978351) hint suggests, let $a$ be the integer where

$$a = x + \sqrt{2020} \implies x = a - \sqrt{2020} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Then let $b$ be the other integer, and use \eqref{eq1A}, to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
b & = \frac{5}{a - \sqrt{2020}} - \sqrt{2020} \\
b + \sqrt{2020} & = \frac{5}{a - \sqrt{2020}} \\
(b + \sqrt{2020})(a - \sqrt{2020}) & = 5 \\
ab - b\sqrt{2020} + a\sqrt{2020} - 2020 & = 5 \\
ab + \sqrt{2020}(-b + a) & = 2025 \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $ab$ and $2025$ are integers, this means $\sqrt{2020}(-b + a)$ must also be an integer. However, due to $\sqrt{2020}$ being irrational and $-b + a$ being an integer, this is only possible if it's $0$, i.e.,

$$b = a \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Using this in \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$a^2 = 2025 \implies a = \pm 45 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Finally, \eqref{eq1A} gives that

$$x = a - \sqrt{2020} \implies x = \pm 45 - \sqrt{2020} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$